# Massive test against azure getting connection refused or service unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

We have a cloud service that gets requests from users, passes the data (two params) to table entities and puts them into cloudtables (using `BatchTableOperations` to `InsertOrReplace` rows). The method is that simple, trying to keep it light and fast (partition key and parttionkey/rowkey pairs issues are controlled).

We need the Cloud Service to cope with about 10k to 15k "concurrent" requests. We first used queues to get users data and a Worker Role to process queue messages and put them into SQL. Although no error rose and no data was lost, processing was too slow for our needs. Now we are trying cloud tables to see if we can process data faster. With smaller amounts of requests, process is fast, but as we get more requests, errors occur and data is lost.

I've set up a few virtual machines for testing in the same virtual network that the cloud service is on, to prevent firewall to stop requests. A jMeter test with 1000 threads and 5 loops, gets 0% error. Same test from 2 virtual machines is ok too. Adding a third machine causes first errors (0.14% requests get Service unavailable 503 errors). Massive tests from 10 machines, 1000 threads and 2 loops gets massive 503 and/or connection refused errors. We have tried scaling cloud service up to 10 instances but that makes little difference on results.

I'm a bit stuck with this issue, and don't know if I'm focussing the problem with the right tools. Any suggestion will be highly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be related to throttling at the storage level. Please look at the scalability targets specified by Windows Azure Storage team here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/04/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx. You may want to try doing the load test keeping these scalability targets into consideration.

Comment: Hi there,

Thanks for the tip. As far as I can see, we are inside de boundaries of table capabilities (at least on first tests)

 The method is quite simple: get two params from URL, create an entity with them an try an InsertOrReplace to the cloud table. If this fails, create a queue message with the data for further processing and to prevent loss of data.

 Anyway, 3 machines, 1000 threads, 5 loops against two instances of the cloud service produce 1-1,5% error (Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection to <URL> refused) and no queue messages are created.

Comment: Are you getting errors from the storage service or from your cloud service? What's the VM size in which the cloud service is deployed (and how many instances - I'm guessing it's just 1)?

Comment: I'm not really getting any error, but refused connections (i.e: "Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection to http://<URL> refused") No timeouts, no 50x error...

The cloud service is a two instance on a xtra-small configuration.(can't get to Azure management right now)

Last test: 4 machines, 1000 threads, 5 loops. Machines 1,2 and 3 had no error, but m4 had 37% refused connections.